# Why multi-gpu faster than single gpu in caffe training?

Tags: machine-learning, caffe, multi-gpu

In the same hardware/software env, With the same net and solver, just differ in command line.

While command line is:

```
caffe-master/build/tools/caffe train --solver=solver_base.prototxt --gpu=6
```

It tasks about 50 seconds per 100 iters.
[image]

While command is :

```
caffe-master/build/tools/caffe train --solver=solver_base.prototxt --gpu=4,5,6,7
```

It takes about 48 seconds per 100 iters.
[image]

As usual, multi-gpu training should cost more time than single-gpu because of cost like replication. So does anyone can tell me why. Thanks very much!

Env:

```
2 * Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2699 v4 @ 2.20GHz
8 * Nvidia Tesla V100 PCIE 16GB
Caffe 1.0.0 / use_cudnn on
Cuda 9.0.176
Cudnn 6.0.21
```

Comment: You're asking why using multiple GPUs finishes faster than using a single GPU, because this is unusual? I am super-confused here because, usually you hope multi-GPU will be faster than single GPU because you use multiple GPUs to achieve better performance…? https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/docs/multigpu.md#scaling-performance says " In general, scaling on 2 GPUs tends to be ~1.8X on average for networks like AlexNet, CaffeNet, VGG, GoogleNet. 4 GPUs begins to have falloff in scaling."

Comment: @AhmedFasih ,  Thanks for your reply.  I mean that to train the same iters, multi-gpu should task more time than single-gpu. As you refered to, In general, scaling on 2 GPUs tends to be ~1.8X on average. In other words,  to train the same iters, if single-gpu cost 0.9t,  2 GPUs shoud cost 1t.

Comment: I read that to mean 1.8X faster: 2 GPUs will cooperate and split the work, completing training 1.8X faster than a single GPU could.